# CodeIgniter search input and pagination URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to create a URL containing string from search form and page from pagination

For example, my base URL is `example.com/search`
When showing the search result it will be `example.com/search/?s=keyword` and when showing the search result from next page it will be `example.com/search/?s=term&p=2` for second page and so on

How to make it like that in CodeIgniter?

Comment: I'm not a master with CodeIgniter, but couldn't you just check the for the `p` argument in the query string, and if it isn't there, than just set the value to `1`. Based on a google search, `$this->input->get('p', TRUE);` will get the value of p in the string, and in php, couldn't you just wrap that in an `if` statement, and be on your way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. here used `page` instead of `p` in URL

```
$keyword = trim($this->input->get('s', TRUE));
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('table_name')->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 5;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['base_url'] = site_url('search/index/?s=' . $keyword);
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
if ($this->input->get('page')) {
    $sgm = (int) trim($this->input->get('page'));
    $segment = $config['per_page'] * ($sgm - 1);
} else {
    $segment = 0;
}

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

// your query
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('table_name')->limit($config['per_page'], $segment)->get();
```

now your URL will be same as you mention in your question